# Why is "the" sometimes optional?

Tags: articles, ellipsis

In my Grammar book I have...

> She's been watching television.

Can we also say...

> She's been watching the television

I just want to know if they are the same.

Comment: We drop the article far more often with TV than with radio.

Comment: @TRomano Can we even drop the article for the radio?

Comment: @NS.X. Yes, we can (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(listening+to+radio)%2C(listening+to+the+radio)%2C(watching+TV)%2C(watching+the+TV)&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28listening%20to%20radio%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28listening%20to%20the%20radio%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28watching%20TV%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28watching%20the%20TV%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @TRomano - True, but there are some contexts where we wouldn't. For example, if someone asked me, "Where's Darla?", and I knew Darla was in her room listening to Q105-FM, I'd probably say, _"She's in her room, listening to the radio."_ (and **not** omit the article). If I were omitting the article, I would probably be talking about something different, like media demographics: _"Fewer people are listening to radio nowadays."_

Answer (score 7):

The two sentences are similar in meaning but not identical.

> She's been watching television.

This sentence means that she has been watching a category of entertainment, television.  It's a general statement.

> She's been watching *the* television.

This sentence is more specific, she has been watching a particular object, the television.  The word *the* is identifying a particular thing among others and bringing it to our attention.  As Stephie pointed out in the comments, this may or may not involve a television that is actually turned on.  It only refers to watching a particular object.

Comment: You. might want to add that "watching *the* television" can be done with the TV off...

Comment: @Stephie - LOL, that's true – and funny. *I'm watching the televsion. I want to make sure that nobody steals it.*

Comment: I think *the* there is optional because the word *television* in that sentence isn't countable and *the* is not used to indicate a particular television.